# How to fire a formload

Tags: c#, winforms

If i wanted to do a button click i would write:

```
this.button1.PerformClick();
```

Let me rephrase my question, I want to create a button that will reload the whole form when clicked, it is possible to close and open the form?

Comment: it's really unclear what you are asking,do you want to trigger Form_load event manually ? or trigger a button click manually? please try to explain your problem clearly

Comment: you just call the method `Form_Load(null,null);`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is that button on the form you want to close and reopen?

Answer (score 2):

```
var myFrom = new Form1();
myForm.Show();
```

If you just want to call the code in Form_Load for the current form, you can just call it (as you do with other functions), since Form_Load is only fired once for each new form.

Comment: Will this open a new form? or just run the code in the Form_Load?

Comment: Both, can you elaborate your question, what is it you want to do?

Comment: I prefer to execute the code in the formload. Though if its not possible than i want to reload the whole form, like closing it and opening it again.

Answer (score 2):

You have your answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Form.Load Event
>
> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

So you need to show your form.

But I guess your intention is to execute the code that you have in a method handling `Form.Load` event. In this case, it would be better to extract that code into a separate method and call that method from both `Form.Load` event handler method and your button `Click` event handler method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //code to load/reload form goes here
}
```

You can make a method like this:

```
private void LoadData()
{
 //code to load/reload form goes here
}
```

And then you can call the same method from both events like so:

```
MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LoadData()
}
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LoadData()
}
```

It's a bit cleaner than having one event call another.